# How to find number of common rows & position in MySQL DB & Python list

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have a table like this:

```
Pos    MD5                         BlockHash
1    randommd51                  randstr1
2    randommd51                  randstr2
3    randommd51                  randstr3
1    randommd52                  randstr2
2    randommd52                  randstr2
3    randommd52                  randstr1
4    randommd52                  randstr7
1    randommd53                  randstr2
2    randommd53                  randstr1
3    randommd53                  randstr2
4    randommd53                  randstr3
1    randommd54                  randstr4
2    randommd54                  randstr55
```

I have another dictionary like this in Python:

```
{ "randommd55": ["randomstr1", "randomstr2", "randomstr1"] }
```

I want to search similar files. MD5 value represent the full file's MD5 value. It will change, even If there is a 1-bit difference in a file.

For each file, I take random 1KB blocks and hash them.

So now, I have a query dictionary consisting of multiple block hash. I want to compare the query blockhash with files inside SQL table.

I want to see how many blockhash match between the query file & the sql files (MD5 is unqiue for each file).

I want to know the following things:

1.) Total common blocks found

2.) Total blocks in the database file

3.) Position of common blocks in database & python dictonary

For example:

File where, MD5 is randommd51  has two common blocks. "randomstr1" and "randomstr2".

So the output will be like this: (not in the exact english format of course).

```
Result 1:
    1.) 2 common blocks found where MD5 is randommd52 in DB

    2.) 3 total blocks are in the DB where MD5 is randommd52 in DB

    3.) Position of common blocks in Query list is: "1,2" and position of common blocks in db are also "1,2"

Result2: 
    1.) 2 common blocks found where MD5 is randommd51 in DB

    2.) 3 total blocks are in the DB where MD5 is randommd51 in DB

    3.) Position of common blocks in Query list is: "1,2" and position of common blocks in db are also "1,3"


............
```

Currently, I am using an SQL query that returns just percentage match between list & SQL database

```
select md5,
       avg( (blockhash in ('randomstr1', 'randomstr2', 'randomstr3') ) as matching_ratio
from t
group by md5
```

How can I modify it to return the above mentioned things?

Comment: . . Show the results that you want.

Comment: I did, I added them in the gray block now. Thanks for reading my question. Is it more clear now?

If not, I can rewrite the question and try to make it more clear maybe

Comment: Edited my output, is it more clear now sir? @GordonLinoff

Comment: In an sql database rows do not have a position. A record will appear at different position in the resultset based on filters and ordering. If you do not have a position stored as a field, the position part of the question is not answerable.

Comment: Makes sense. I edited my table @Shadow . Now i have a position

Comment: I figured out everything, I just want to know, how to get the position?